# Failed OAuth Using gtm-oauth2 for Instagram

Tags: objective-c, ios, oauth, instagram

I have set up the OAuth request following the documentation for a "Non-Google Service" and I get 90% of this working. The app brings up a web view where I can login to Instagram using the correct access token for my app and accept the scope request but once I accept the request I get the following error:

```
Error Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x6b7ab00 {data=<7b22636f 6465223a 20343030 2c202265 72726f72 5f747970 65223a20 224f4175 74684578 63657074 696f6e22 2c202265 72726f72 5f6d6573 73616765 223a2022 596f7520 6d757374 20696e63 6c756465 20612076 616c6964 20636c69 656e745f 69642c20 20202020 20202020 20202020 72657370 6f6e7365 5f747970 652c2061 6e642072 65646972 6563745f 75726920 70617261 6d657465 7273227d>}
Error data:
{
    code = 400;
    "error_message" = "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters";
    "error_type" = OAuthException;
}
```

It seems like the controller is attempting to complete the OAuth transaction against google.com instead of api.instagram.com.

Here is my objective-c code to set up and invoke the controller:

```
static NSString *const kKeychainItemName = @"Instagram OAuth2";
static NSString *const kClientID = @"xxxxxxxxx"; // Removed for security
static NSString *const kClientSecret = @"xxxxxxxxx"; // Removed for security

static NSString *const authURLString = @"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/";
static NSString *const tokenURLString = @"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/";
static NSString *const redirectURI = @"http://google.com/NeverGonnaFindMe/";

...

NSURL *tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:tokenURLString];

// Set up the OAuth request
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication
            authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"Instagram API"
            tokenURL:tokenURL
            redirectURI:redirectURI
            clientID:kClientID
            clientSecret:kClientSecret
         ];

// Specify the appropriate scope string, if any, according to the service's API documentation
auth.scope = @"basic likes comments relationships";

NSURL *authURL = [NSURL URLWithString:authURLString];

// Display the authentication view
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]
                      initWithAuthentication:auth
                      authorizationURL:authURL
                      keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                      delegate:self
                      finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)                                                     
                    ];
// Capture the Cookie to delete later
viewController.browserCookiesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram.com/"];

// Now push our sign-in view
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: hey can you share the example with me plz plz plz?

Comment: I posted the example on my blog [http://ifjoshrantheworld.com/instagram-oauth-login-for-ios-objective-c](http://ifjoshrantheworld.com/instagram-oauth-login-for-ios-objective-c)

Comment: Hi Josh i have login succesfully and also get accesstoken but don't know how to share image in instagram can you help me?

Comment: The only way to share image in Instagram is through the Instagram app. This might help [http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/)

Comment: i get the token id from instagram api but now i don't know to how to post image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/instagram-api-developers/SUYPX7ZQHhs

It was the token URL that was incorrect.  Correct token URL is: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token/

Comment: Just made the exact same error and scratched my head for a good while; glad I found this!